# Retain element screen position after adding a new element before it in DOM

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have a div containing two spans which hold text:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <span id="span-one" class="name-letters">One</span>
    <span id="span-two" class="name-letters">Two</span>
</div>
```

I perform a CSS animation on these spans to move one element away from the other (took out browser prefixes for better legibility) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/769py6t8/):

```
#span-two {
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slide {
    from {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
}
```

**Example:**

**start:**

```
One Two
```

**stop:**

```
One          Two
```

Now, I would like to add a third span, once the animation has completed, next to the first span. However, I would like the second span to keep its animation end position.

**Example:**

**what I want:**

```
One Three    Two
```

**what I get:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcgtveo5/1/)

```
One Three          Two
```

This is because I add to the margin-left attribute of the second span for it to move in the animation. So, when I add a new element before it, the second span moves further to meet the margin-left value that was set. **My Question:** How can I achieve this without moving the second spans position after the third span is added?

Comment: How do you add `Three` element? With javascript?

Comment: Yes. Check out the JSFiddle link I provided.

Comment: Interestingly [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609361/retain-element-position-after-css-animation) appears to be quite similar???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set span #3 positioned absolutely (or `fixed`), but without specifying `top` and `left` values (!):

```css
#span-three {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and

```
span.id = "span-three";
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gcgtveo5/2/

Comment: This seems to be the only approach. I was hoping for another way, because using an absolutely positioned item may complicate things slightly if I adjust the relatively positioned items attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write pure javascript, but could you do something like this instead of the absolute positioned span?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
    <span id="span-one" class="name-letters">One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="spanThreeContainer">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <span id="span-two" class="name-letters">Two</span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

`.container {width:33.33%; float:left;}`

and then append your new span to '#spanThreeContainer'?

Comment: Certainly an interesting approach and nice way to avoid using absolutely positioned items. However, it seems there still might be some problems with the positioning which might require a lot of fiddling around with the attributes. http://jsfiddle.net/y2tt7zz0/1/

Comment: i see the positioning problem you're talking about. i added a min-height to .container and that seems to fix the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/y2tt7zz0/2/